# Checking Even Numbers using Array.every() method in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using a function that takes an array and returns true if all its values are even and false otherwise.

My Code is below and passed array is [ -2, 2, -2, 2 ]

```
function checkAllEven(arr) {
  return arr.every(x=> { x % 2 === 0 });
}
-------------
Output: False
```

But when I removed curly braces, it works correctly and return true.

```
function checkAllEven(arr) {
  return arr.every(x=> x % 2 === 0 );
}
-------------
Output: True
```

Just Want to know why it is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `return` if you have curly braces:

```
function checkAllEven(arr) {
  return arr.every(x=> { return x % 2 === 0 });
}
```